# Confronting "unacceptable character #x0095: special characters are not allowed in "<unicode string>", position 268" Error in Python yaml.load

Tags: python, yaml

I am confronting "unacceptable character #x0095: special characters are not allowed in "", position 25" error message when transferring YAML format to Python dictionary object.
What would be the possible solution?

```
d = 'tended (Journaled)"\n  - "\x95 Support plug and play"\n'
a = yaml.load(d)
```

The string to be transferred is abridged, not a proper YAML format, but I guess it's irrelevant in this case.
I'm using Python3

Comment: Unicode code point hex 95 is a unicode control char. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters -- which character do you want to have displayed?

Comment: Showing the string is not my objective. I'm trying to clean up the messy data into an analyzable Python format... Any command or encoding I can do before executing yaml.load() to avoid this error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2770814) clearly states that a YAML stream only uses the printable subset of the Unicode character set. Except for NEL (`\x85`), characters in the *C1 control block is not allowed* (i.e. characters `\x80`-`\x9F`).

This is almost valid YAML:

```
d = 'tended (Journaled)"\n - " Support plug and play"\n'
```

You just need a `"` in front of it and `:` after the key:

```
d = '"tended (Journaled)":\n - " Support plug and play"\n'
```

(although I'm not sure if Journaled is correct English)

The following is not YAML:

```
d = '"tended (Journaled)":\n  - "\x95 Support plug and play"\n'
```

because `\x95` is in the C1 control block. You will have to replace those characters by hand, or drop them.

There is not much in `ruamel.yaml` that helps you  convert such illegal characters, but you can use the `Reader`'s illegal character regex to scan for the illegal characters and drop them:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.reader import Reader

yaml = YAML(typ='safe')


def strip_invalid(s):
    res = ''
    for x in s:
        if Reader.NON_PRINTABLE.match(x):
            # res += '\\x{:x}'.format(ord(x))
            continue
        res += x
    return res

d = '"tended (Journaled)":\n  - "\x95 Support plug and play"\n'

print(yaml.load(strip_invalid(d)))
```

which gives:

```
{'tended (Journaled)': [' Support plug and play']}
```

without any further manual intervention.

If you uncomment the line

```
        # res += '\\x{:x}'.format(ord(x))
```

you get as output:

```
{'tended (Journaled)': ['\x95 Support plug and play']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the messy data for invalid characters. Fortunately, the YAML reader has an Exception that yields the necessary data:

```
import yaml

try:
    d = 'tended (Journaled)"\n  - "\x95 Support plug and play"\n'
    a = yaml.load(d)
except yaml.YAMLError as e:
    print("Parsing YAML string failed")
    print("Reason:", e.reason)
    print("At position: {0} with encoding {1}".format(e.position, e.encoding))
    print("Invalid char code:", e.character)
```

If you run this code, it displays exactly that your character `\x95` is the culprit. Now you have to replace/repair/ask the user until no exception is thrown.

Comment: Any method to get the code running but leave the \x95 as the way it is?

Comment: The e.position is a single integer. How do I find the corresponding line and and place in the yaml file?